# How does a processor know the amount of time it should hold the address on the address lines

Tags: clock, microprocessor, delay

How does a CPU know how much time it keeps the address on the address line or even data because considering the CPU relies on clock to sync its operations.

I've seen the datasheet of the 6502 microprocessor and it holds the address on the address line for 10 ns and the clock pulse width is 500 ns and from the rising edge to next rising edge is 1 us (1 MHz clock), so how does the microprocessor know 10 ns have passed.

Comment: `holds the address on the address [lines] for 10ns` referenced to *just what*?

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the term *hold time* (complementary to *setup time*, neither of which is a pulse width). Can you include a timing diagram/waveform for the parameter(s) of interest?

Comment: A processor is nothing more then a fancy state machine that is clock driven with a lot of logic. Change the clock frequency changes the timing.

Answer (score 4):

The CPU doesn't even know that. It's just a bunch of logic gates.

Due to the internal delays in the logic gates it has, and how the clock affects to all the signals that you can monitor externally, it just takes some time to update some signals like the address bus or data bus so they are being held stable for some time after read or write bus cycle terminates.

And the bunch of logic gates is just engineered with the delays being suitable for the task, i.e. how the data, address and control signals relate to each other, by designers adjusting the amount of gates in the signal path for example, or on the clock path.

Comment: So from what you say,when the address is sent from the program counter register by enabling it(by the control unit) it takes 10ns until it disappears again

Comment: @Johngreg No, I did not say that and that also does not happen. Maybe you have some misconception what hold time means in this context? Hold time means how long the address on the bus is still valid after a read or write operation has ended before it changes to next address for the next read or write operation.

Comment: My question was how does the cpu just keep the data or the address stable for a given amount of time(wether the time is setup time or hold time) if a clock tick would cause the cpu to execute the next instruction What mechanism does it use to hold the address for a given time

Comment: It updates the address with some internal delay after a clock tick and it's stable until it gets updates again after the next clock tick. The designers just need to guarantee that there is some specification and that the chips can meet the specification even due to manufacturing tolerances.

Answer (score 4):

The processor just behaves the way it's built.

The designer of the 6502 will have characterised how it behaves, at various voltages, temperatures and clock rates, and put that information into the data sheet.

It's up to the circuit designer to read and understand the data sheet, and then run the 6502 at a suitable clock speed, and use peripherals around it that can work with its timings.

Answer (score 2):

The 6502 has no knowledge of how long a cycle takes.  It is up to the designer to ensure setup and hold times are met on address, data and control lines to ensure data is transfered to and from the processor.

The RDY input on the 6502 allows the board designer to extend a cycle by adding wait states (extra clock cycles) to access slower I/O devices or memory.  This would be normally coupled to Chip Selects for a specific devices that need extra clock cycles.

If external circuitry pulls the RDY input low synchronized to Φ1, wait state are inserted into the present cycle.  Used for slow devices or to single step through programs or DMA access.

From [Princeton.edu](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Emae412/HANDOUTS/Datasheets/6502.pdf)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The hold time is a fancy name for a delay between a clock edge and the update of the address pins.

It’s not as if the processor “wants” to hold it. It just how long it takes for the clock edge to propagate internally and cause the address bus latch to update its state. It’s a measure of how “slow” it is in fact.

Gates don’t update their outputs instantly, wires in the processor don’t carry signals instantly either. It all takes time.

Think of the clock edge like it was the edge of a tall wave. It takes time to spread across the lake, it takes time to move in the processor as well.

Answer (score 2):

> holds the address on the address line for 10 ns

More accurately said: *"holds the address on the address line for **at least** 10 ns **after falling edge of PHI2**"*. This applies for 65C02, for the original 6502 the delay is at least 30 ns.

In this case the particular delay is probably just characterized: it is whatever delay is in the hardware, and the datasheet tells the system designer how long the delay is.

But if the designer of a microchip wants to create a longer delay for whatever purpose, they can add a chain of buffers:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvuWrL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The delay for a single buffer varies by manufacturing process, temperature and supply voltage, but typically it is stable to within 50% error. The designer would insert enough buffers to always satisfy the minimum requirement.